# How do I improve this RSpec code in rspec way?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, sinatra, rspec2

I'm new to Ruby and RSpec. I come from Java background that's why my test really looks like junit code. I'm trying to learn more about RSpec but I don't quite understand `subject`, `let`, `!let`. So, if anybody can guide me to clean up this code, I'd be really appreciated.

I have sinatra, RSpec which it's doing Sign-in with Twitter.

```
get '/login/twitter' do
  begin
    request_token = TwitterService.new.authentication_request_token

    session[:request_token_twitter] = request_token

    redirect request_token.authorize_url
  rescue Exception => e
    logger.error(e.message)
    redirect '/'
  end  
end

get '/login/twitter/success' do
  request_token = session[:request_token_twitter]
  twitter_service = TwitterService.new
  access_token = twitter_service.authorize(request_token, params[:oauth_verifier])

  begin
    twitter_user_info = twitter_service.verify_credentials

    twitter_id = twitter_user_info["id"]
    response.set_cookie("auth_token", :value => twitter_id, :path => '/')
    response.set_cookie(@social_flag, :value => "t", :path => '/')

    expected_user = @user_manager.find_by_id(twitter_id.to_s)

    if expected_user.is_null?
      twitter_user = User.new(twitter_id, access_token.token, access_token.secret, "t")
      twitter_user.save

      logger.info("Saving ...")
      logger.info("Twitter ID #{twitter_id}")

      redirect '/signup'
    else
      expected_user.token = access_token.token
      expected_user.secret = access_token.secret
      expected_user.update 

      logger.info("Updating token and secret ...")
      logger.info("Twitter ID #{twitter_id}")
    end

  rescue Exception => e
    logger.error(e.message)
    logger.error("There's something wrong with Twitter and user cannot log in")
    redirect '/'
  end

  redirect '/t'
end
```

And here's my RSpec. I know it's really ugly.

```
describe "Twitter route" do
    include TwitterOAuth

    def app
        Sinatra::Application
    end

    context "/login/twitter" do
        it "should redirect to twitter authorized url" do
            request_token = OpenStruct.new
            request_token.authorize_url = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token"

            TwitterService.any_instance.stub(:authentication_request_token).and_return(request_token)

            get '/login/twitter'
            last_response.header["Location"].should include "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token"
            last_response.status.should eql 302
            session[:request_token_twitter].authorize_url.should == "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token"
        end

        it "should redirect back to home page if error occurs" do
            TwitterService.any_instance.stub(:authentication_request_token).and_raise("Unauthorized")

            get '/login/twitter'

            last_response.header["Location"].should include "http://example.org/"
            last_response.status.should eql 302
            session[:request_token_twitter].should eql nil
        end

        it "should save a user after a success callback from twitter" do
            user_manager = UserManager.new

            access_token = OpenStruct.new
            access_token.token = "token"
            access_token.secret = "secret"

            TwitterService.any_instance.stub(:authorize).with(anything(), anything()).and_return(access_token)
            TwitterService.any_instance.stub(:verify_credentials).and_return({"id" => "id1"})

            get '/login/twitter/success'

            last_response.header["Location"].should include "/signup"
            rack_mock_session.cookie_jar["auth_token"].should eql "id1"
            rack_mock_session.cookie_jar["s_flag"].should eql "t"
            last_response.status.should eql 302

            user_manager = UserManager.new
            expected_user = user_manager.find_by_id("id1")
            expected_user.id.should eql "id1"
            expected_user.token.should eql "token"
            expected_user.secret.should eql "secret"
        end

        it "should update user token and secret if the user already exists" do
            User.new("id1", "token", "secret", "t").save

            access_token = OpenStruct.new
            access_token.token = "token1"
            access_token.secret = "secret1"

            TwitterService.any_instance.stub(:authorize).with(anything(), anything()).and_return(access_token)
            TwitterService.any_instance.stub(:verify_credentials).and_return({"id" => "id1"})

            get '/login/twitter/success'

            last_response.header["Location"].should include "/t"
            rack_mock_session.cookie_jar["auth_token"].should eql "id1"
            rack_mock_session.cookie_jar["s_flag"].should eql "t"
            last_response.status.should eql 302

            user_manager = UserManager.new
            expected_user = user_manager.find_by_id("id1")
            expected_user.id.should eql "id1"
            expected_user.token.should eql "token1"
            expected_user.secret.should eql "secret1"
        end

        it "should redirect back to the home page" do
            access_token = OpenStruct.new
            access_token.token = "token1"
            access_token.secret = "secret1"

            TwitterService.any_instance.stub(:authorize).with(anything(), anything()).and_return(access_token)
            TwitterService.any_instance.stub(:verify_credentials).and_raise

            get '/login/twitter/success'

            last_response.header["Location"].should include "http://example.org/"
            end

        end
end
```

Any improvement I'd be grateful not just the code. May be if I miss something obvious.

Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, a lot happening here!

First off, you should try to stick to one test per example. Your examples are currently testing a whole bunch of behavior, which means that your tests are rather all-or-nothing, and may make it unclear what specifically breaks if you've broken something.

First off, I'm going to add a new matcher. You'd usually put this in somewhere like spec/support/matchers.rb or something. It's just going to extend rspec so that we can test that a response was a redirect, and that the redirect goes to a given location:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :redirect_to do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    actual.should be_redirect
    actual.location.should include expected
  end
end
```

Now, onto the code!

The unannotated source is here: https://gist.github.com/cheald/5908093 - that will probably be less annoying to read :)

`let` defines a method that will run exactly once per example, no matter how many times it's invoked. This lets us have a "variable" that is defined at example-time, which lets us override it in nested examples. Here, I have `access_token` defined up top, but we'll `let` another access_token in a deeper example. This suite doesn't really show this off too well, but this lets you do nice things where something from one `let` is referenced in another. Imagine, if you will, that we have

```
let(:user) { user_manager.find(access_token.id) }
```

This will use the deepest-nested user_manager and deepest-nested access_token without having to redeclare user in each nested scope. Handy!

`let` blocks aren't invoked until they're used (as opposed to `let!` blocks, which are always invoked when declared)

```
describe "Twitter route" do
  include TwitterOAuth

  let(:app) {  Sinatra::Application }
  let(:request_token) { double("request_token", authorize_url: "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token") }
  let(:access_token) { double("token", token: "token", secret: "secret") }
  let(:user_manager) { UserManager.new }
```

You'll notice that I've broken your tests up into nested contexts, to group similar behavior. That is, all the tests that should pass with an authorized token get nested under the authorized token context, and our `before` block sets up the context so that all examples in this context get a valid token.

We also go ahead and do the `get` in the before block, so we can just test the results directly.

```
  context "/login/twitter" do
    context "with an authorized token" do
      before do
        TwitterService.any_instance.stub(:authentication_request_token).and_return(request_token)
        TwitterService.any_instance.stub(:authorize).with(anything(), anything()).and_return(access_token)
        TwitterService.any_instance.stub(:verify_credentials).and_return({"id" => "id1"})
        get '/login/twitter'
      end
```

You see here that I'm using our new matcher. It lets us check for a redirect to a given URL in one test.

```
      it "should redirect to twitter authorized url" do
        last_response.should redirect_to "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token"
      end

      it "should set a the request token in the session" do
        session[:request_token_twitter].authorize_url.should == "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token"
      end

      context "after a success callback" do
        let(:user) { user_manager.find_by_id("id1") }
        context "when there is not an existing user" do
          before do
            get '/login/twitter/success'
          end

          it "should redirect to /signup" do
            last_response.should redirect_to "/signup"
          end

          it "should set an auth_token cookie" do
            rack_mock_session.cookie_jar["auth_token"].should == "id1"
          end

          it "should set an s_flag cookie" do
            rack_mock_session.cookie_jar["s_flag"].should == "t"
          end
```

Here you'll see `subject`. It just defines what the variable `subject` returns, and makes `its` blocks operate on it. In this case, the subject is the `User` record. Since `subject` is the user record, I can use the more concise form to check its attributes.

```
          context "the authenticated user" do
            subject { user }
            its(:id)     { should == "id1" }
            its(:token)  { should == "token" }
            its(:secret) { should == "secret" }
          end
        end
```

You'll see here that I provide a new definition for `access_token`. When these examples run, the before block way up at the top (that sets up the "authorized token") will use this `access_token` rather than the one defined way up there. This lets us override the variables used to set up the context with variables specific to this particular context.

```
        context "when there is an existing user" do
          let(:access_token) { double("token", token: "newtoken", secret: "newsecret") }
          before do
            User.new("id1", "oldtoken", "oldsecret", "t").save
            get '/login/twitter/success'
          end

          it "should set an auth_token cookie" do
            rack_mock_session.cookie_jar["auth_token"].should == "id1"
          end

          it "should set an s_flag cookie" do
            rack_mock_session.cookie_jar["s_flag"].should == "t"
          end

          it "should redirect to /t" do
            last_response.should redirect_to "/t"
          end

          context "the authenticated user" do
            subject { user }
            its(:id)     { should == "id1" }
            its(:token)  { should == "newtoken" }
            its(:secret) { should == "newsecret" }
          end
        end
      end
    end

    context "with an invalid token" do
      before do
        TwitterService.any_instance.stub(:authentication_request_token).and_raise("Unauthorized")
        get '/login/twitter'
      end

      it "should redirect back to home page if error occurs" do
        last_response.should redirect_to "http://example.org/"
      end

      it "should not set a session value" do
        session[:request_token_twitter].should be_nil
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Trying to create contexts where certain cookies existed was melting my brain. Thanks a lot Chris!